# Ember deferReadiness / pause during runtime

Tags: cordova, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I am developing a Phonegap App with Ember.js. Withing my Application I am using authentication via oauth (Ember-Simple-Auth). While launching my app, the readiness is deferred until my tokens are refreshed and I can send authorized requests to my backend.

I am now having an issue with phonegap that sometimes a token expires while I am not in my app. When I now change to my app I will have an expired token, but since the whole bootstrap process of ember is not retriggered (in that case ember simple auth would realize that the token is expired and refresh it) I am authorized with an expired token. Is there a possibility to defer the readiness of the app on some phonegap events (resume) withing that trigger the refresh and only then "release" the app?

Update:

I just checked that I can't deferReadiness after the app was once ready. Question is how I could prevent the applicaiton from entering another route (--> calling a model hook) before I haven't refreshed the access_token? Or is it possible to force the app on the transition to stay in the "loading" state? (I have some of my backend calls outside of the model hook in order to show the screen directly and add additional content asyncronoun)